# Ramp function for Intel SSE

Tags: c++, optimization, signal-processing, intel, sse

I'm porting my OsX DSP library to Windows. Started from vDSP_ramp, that is used heavily. This function generates a ramp of increasing values C[i] = C[i-1] + A.

This is my SSE version using intrinsics (I add an incremental vector to accumulator and store)

```
 __m128 acc = {A[0],A[0]+(*B),A[0]+2*(*B), A[0]+3*(*B)};//_mm_set1_ps(0.0);
    float i1 = 4*(*B);
    __m128 inc = {i1,i1,i1,i1};

    int ln = N/4/4;

    for(int i=0; i<ln; i++) {
        __m128 a1 =  _mm_add_ps(acc, inc);
        __m128 a2 =  _mm_add_ps(a1, inc);
        __m128 a3 =  _mm_add_ps(a2, inc);
        acc       =  _mm_add_ps(a3, inc);

        _mm_store_ps(C, a1);
        _mm_store_ps(C+4, a2);
        _mm_store_ps(C+8, a3);
        _mm_store_ps(C+12, acc);
        C+=16;
    }
```

I even unrolled the loop, but it still takes 5x more time than original vdsp_ramp function.

How can I optimise this more? What is wrong here?

Edit1: reference code:

```
void BSDSP_vramp(
             const float *A,
             const float *B,
             float       *C,
             unsigned long  N) {

for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    C[i] = (*A)+i*(*B);

}
```

}

Comment: dependency vs multiplication?

Comment: What is the original code? What is a MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your new code? On which platforms did you run them? How did you measure the execution time?

Comment: Reference code added to the original post. Compiled with LLVM under XCode measured using Instruments time profiler. I started from a single _mm_add_ps and _mm_store_ps.. This was so bad, that I decided to unroll the loop a bit and indeed helped just a bit :)

Answer (score 3):

You have a data dependency between `a1` and `a2`, `a2` and `a3`, `a3` and `acc`, and `acc` and `a1`.  This sets an absolute floor on the speed at which your loop can execute of one loop iteration every 4*(latency of `ADDPS`) cycles = 1 loop iteration / 12-16 cycles (the exact figure depends on the architecture you are targeting).

Dependencies like this are a cardinal sin of vectorization.  Just Don't Do It.

Instead, compute the initial four vectors, and add four times the increment to each of them on each pass through the loop.  This way, they don't depend on each other, and your loop can run 3-4x faster.  You may still be somewhat slower than `vDSP_vramp`, as you aren't doing anything special about alignment, and you aren't taking advantage of AVX on machines that support it, but that will at least get you in the right ballpark.